# Django test migration fails for sqllite3 backend

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlite

when running following test command:

```
python -W ignore manage.py test --pattern=*p --settings=mysite.settings_test -v 2
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Applying app_connections.0046_feefocredential_expire_at...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 326, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "[]": syntax error
```

Strangely the migration that fails is just adding a new field:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11.1 on 2018-07-13 14:55
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app_connections', '0045_auto_20180613_0844'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='feefocredential',
            name='expire_at',
            field=models.DateTimeField(null=True),
        )
    ]
```

which results in following sql:

```
# python manage.py sqlmigrate app_connections 0046
BEGIN;
--
-- Raw SQL operation
--

            ALTER TABLE app_connections_feefocredential
            ADD COLUMN fetch_merchant_ids VARCHAR[] NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}';
            ;
COMMIT;
```

and db settings:

```
#cat mysite/settings_test.py 
from .settings import *

# [START dbconfig]
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': ':memory:',
    }
}
# [END dbconfig]

INTERNAL_IPS = ['127.0.0.1', ]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
SITE_URL = 'localhost:8000'
NOTIFICATIONS_API_URL = "http://notifications-service"

DEBUG = True
ENABLE_DEBUG_TOOLBAR = True
APPDB_EXPORT_ENABLED = False
```

Note the migration for actual db which is postgres works fine, so its likely something to do with sqllite backend generation. Is there any other place that I can check where it fails, as the line in particular that fails is too obscure to say the reason:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/bce29f10a2ee991e70133b71e0de2a6cf4260f0f/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py#L326

Comment: What is that command?

Comment: Please show your DATABASES setting.